# PostgreSql connecting locally to remote server GCP

Tags: java, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, oracle-sqldeveloper, datasource

I am trying to connect locally by using pgAdmin or sql developer to the remote database. Database is on GCP however I dont know what I am missing.
On the screenshot

It is configured in GCP as a Cloud SQL instance and the problem is that initially  It did not have public IP only private IP. So I exposed one by following the instruction from: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/authorize-networks#authorized-networks

This is how currently looks like (I am using username and password from the application.properties of a java project that is in VM instance to connect to sqlDeveloper):

[screen of the configuration of CloudSql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n905s.png)

And the configuration of the sql developer:

[sqlDeveloper setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D10ZM.png)

There is definitely something missing or I am doing it wrong.

Can someone help me with connecting locally to the database.
I am totally new to GCP. I am used to configuration files like in tomcat context.xml

Comment: Do you use your own VM (compute engine) or do you use Cloud SQL?

Comment: it's Cloud SQL. I know that there is a privite address. So i tried to added to the connection details in sql developer however it didn't work.

Comment: Can you share screenshot of the connectivity configuration of your Cloud SQL instance? Hide public IP addresses

Comment: I have added the screenshot to the main post. The thing is that i have only private IP, no public IP

Comment: Please share more details. Don't hide it in pictures

Comment: Not sure what else do you want me to share what more details do you need.  I hided partly ip address.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't a public IP, you can't connect your instance from outside GCP. So you can't (easily) from your local environment.

I [wrote an article on this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-sql-with-private-ip-only-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-de4ac23ce98a). Have a look, you will understand what's the problem and how to solve it (the hard way!)

Comment: so there is no way to have that public ID ? what if there will be possibility to create another instance of the database which will be copy of the existing one (lets say something like dev env for testing purposes) but this time the new instance will have public ID - is there such way?

Comment: Have a look to the documentation. It's possible to have a public IP, you need to configure it

Comment: thanks, i managed expose public IP however it didnt help to connect to the sql developer

Comment: Sure, because you need to authorize networks. for example your IP. You will be able to find tutorials on this.

Comment: is't the authorization of the network done during the creation of the public IP

Comment: You have a public IP, then you have to grant external IP to reach your database. Or you can let a public IP and use Cloud SQL proxy

Comment: i did that by following this  instructions - https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/authorize-networks#authorized-networks

however it did not help to connect.

Comment: This is not a good practice but in order to discard issues with Cloud SQL, you could temporarily open the database to any network by specifying `0.0.0.0/0`. If after having public ip enabled and the authorized network `0.0.0.0/0`, you are not able to connect, then you should double-check the database client configuration. If you are able to connect with `0.0.0.0/0`, then the issue is mainly with your client ip and the allowed network CIDR.

Comment: @AntonioRamirez I deleted the public ip which i created previously and i added one more time the address which you suggested however it didnt work. I think there is someting missing or i am doing it wrong.

Comment: Have a look at this video[1]. In the first 6 minutes, he pretty much goes through the setup you need for pgadmin and postgres. [1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SPvA858VnX0.

Comment: @AntonioRamirez thank you for link it was very helpfull! Unfortunatelly i couldn't connect. I think the reason lies down on some sort of a firewall. Because i tried in command line ping to the host ot cloud sql and i was getting timeout.

Comment: It is expected that pings will not work to Cloud SQL instances because Cloud SQL instances do not allow icmp traffic. Have you tried installing Cloud SDK and connecting to your instance with gcloud commands? https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/connect